# start playframework 2.7.2 via docker in dev environment

Tags: java, scala, docker, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to start a project with playframework 2.7.2 in a docker but at the moment but the sbt run command starts the server and then stops so I don't really understand how to start my project via docker?

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM bigtruedata/scala:2.10.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git 

RUN wget -O- "https://piccolo.link/sbt-1.2.8.tgz" \
    |  tar xzf - -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
    && sbt exit

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 9000 9443

RUN sbt update 

COPY app/ .

CMD ["sbt", "run"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    play:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/play/Dockerfile

        volumes:
            - ./app:/app

        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
            - "9443:9443"
        command: "sbt run"
```

My stdout from docker on start:

```
play_1  | [info]    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.12;2.7.2!play-docs_2.12.jar (692ms)
play_1  | [info]    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.12;2.7.2!play-omnidoc_2.12.jar (831ms)
play_1  | [info] Done updating.
play_1  | [warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
play_1  | 
play_1  | --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
play_1  | 
play_1  | [info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000
play_1  | 
play_1  | (Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)
play_1  | 
play_1  | [info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Stopping server...
play_1  | [info] Compiling 7 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /app/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
play_1  | [info] Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.12' for Scala 2.12.8. Compiling...
play_1  | [info]   Compilation completed in 18.801s.
play_1  | [info] Done compiling.
play_1  | [info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):
play_1  | 
play_1  |     play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
play_1  |     play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
play_1  |     play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
play_1  | 
play_1  | [info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev) (no global state)
play_1  | 
play_1  | [success] Total time: 53 s, completed May 14, 2019 1:12:39 PM
```

Comment: Not really answering your question but `sbt run` should only be used for local development. `sbt dist` is what can be used for deployment (docker or not). Read more here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Deploying#Deploying-your-application

Comment: Yep is local development but the server stops soon after it is tried to launch.

Comment: Ok. how do you run it?

Comment: via CMD ["sbt", "run"]

Comment: yeah, I mean you do `docker run...`? try `docker run -d ...`

Comment: docker-compose up --build

Comment: try adding `--detach` as well

Comment: It doesn't work any better.

Comment: can you share your docker-compose.yml as well?

Comment: Yep, I edited the content of the question

Comment: Again, not really answering but are you sure you can use Play 2.7 with sbt 0.13?

Comment: Okay, I didn't see that I had an old version of sbt, I just did the test with the new version. It doesn't work any better.

Comment: Okay, I found it, why didn't it work. You have to activate the tty. 
tty: true in your docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You can create a deployment archive, by following the guide here

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Deploying

and once you have the tar or zip, you can create a dockerfile as follows

```
FROM openjdk:8u151-jre-slim
ADD playBinary.tar app    
CMD ["./app/playBinary/bin/playBinary"]
```

You can then start the application like

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 <image-name>
```

For running it in dev, you can have a small utility script (its quite ugly) but it should work

```
#!/bin/bash
sbt run
function finish {
        sleep infinity
}
trap finish EXIT
```

and add the following lines to your Dockerfile

```
COPY ./init-script.sh /init-script.sh
RUN chmod +x /init-script.sh
CMD ["/init-script.sh"]
```

Comment: I don't want deploy. I just want run via docker my projet for the moment

Comment: sorry my bad missed it, updated the answer! Let me know if it works